# Static equilibrium question

Tags: torque, statics

I was doing some static equilibrium problems and I came across this problem which should be easy to solve, but is posing quite a challenge. I want to point out that this is **not** homework, just plain old studying. By the way, I don't know how to format mathematical equations and I think writing them out here without any formatting is a mess, so I took phtographs of the relevant bits. If any brave soul feels up to the task, I'd greatly appreciate it :)

This problem is from this [book (8th edition)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1133954057), and instead of copying the entire problem and the image, I took a picture of everything:

[image]

So, I know that the sum of forces on the x axis, the sum of forces on the y axis and the torque considered from any origin must all equal 0 for equilibrium to happen.

First, I drew this simple diagram with all the forces applied on the body:

[image]

Then I wrote this simple set of equations:

[image]

If I solve this to get the maximum mass M that can be hanged, I get this result:

m + M = m/2 + M

Which is nonsense! This cannot be correct... So, I went back to the drawing board trying to figure out what was wrong. The only thing I could think of was that I was assuming the normal force R was perpendicular to the ground, which I think it is (it's called *normal* for some reason). However, the result I'm getting does not make any sense, so there must be an error somewhere!

Comment: I'm not certain but suspect from the wording that you should find two solutions, only one of which has a value $\mu < cot(\theta)$ . The other thing I'd do is calculate the total horizontal force (to the right) as a function of `M` and go from there.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Hmm, I'm not sure that I understand what you mean by two solutions. Based on the description of the problem there should only be one maximum value for the mass M. I also checked the answers, which don't have any step-by-step explanations, and there's only one formula for the max value of M.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Also, `T = cotg(theta)*(m/2 + M)*g`. That's a no brainer. But then I do `F = T = Us * R = Us * (m + M) * g` and the result is `Us*(m + M)*g = cotg(theta)*(m/2 + M)*g`. You can remove the `g`s from both sides, etc. You end up with `m + M = m/2 + M`, which was my issue...

Comment: Imagine a pulley on _P_. Would the forces on the bar be the same? In this case since the rope can slide past _P_ the tension on the rope is _not equal_ to the reaction force with the bar.

Comment: @ja72 The problem explicitly states that the rope is "a very rough rope". IMO that should be interpreted as there's a segment of rope connecting the wall to the point P on the bar an there's another segment of rope from which M is hanging. If the rope is very rough, then it is 'glued' to the bar. If it were a pulley, then the mass M would press the bar against the wall (no force T), but that is not the case here.

Comment: This is exactly what makes this problem so interesting and challenging. It is the treatment of the rope and rod connection that makes all the difference. The question of how the rope tension affects the problem, or simply by splitting the rope in two pieces as suggested would suffice.

Comment: Not to be a spoilsport, but you can find the solution in the student manual using Amazon's "Look inside" feature:  http://www.amazon.com/Student-Solutions-Jewetts-Scientists-Engineers/dp/1439048541/ref=sr_1_4?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1402492728&sr=1-4&keywords=physics+for+scientists+and+engineers+with+modern+physics+8th+edition  I can post the solution page if you can't access it.  Just ask :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Actually, I can't find it... but it'd be awesome if you could post the solution. Maybe from that I'll see what I did wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice problem.

If the rope is split into two pieces, each being a two force member (can only have tension) then treat the problem first with infinite friction at the base to find the required friction force for equilibrium.

[image: Sketch]

$$ \begin{align} P_x - A_x & = 0 \\
A_y - m g - M g & = 0 \\
m g \frac{\ell}{2} \cos\theta + M g \ell \cos\theta - P_x \ell \sin \theta & = 0 \end{align} $$

Three equations for three unknowns $A_x,\ A_y,\ P_x$. Now set $A_x$ according to static friction and find $M$. The rest follows. The above is solved for:

$$ A_y = (M+m) g \\ A_x = (M+\frac{m}{2}) g \cot\theta \\ P_x = A_x $$

and thus $M \le \frac{m ( \cos\theta - 2 \mu_s \sin\theta)}{2(\mu_s \sin\theta-\cos\theta)}$. The system is stable only when $M>0$ which occurs when $\frac{\cot\theta}{2} < \mu_s < \cot\theta $.

Comment: But isn't `Ax = Us * Ay`? If so, how do you get that result for `M`?

Comment: First I find the solution for any $A_x$ (rough surface problem). The find the $M$ which makes $A_x = \mu_s A_y$.

Comment: Alright, I understand perfectly now. Thank you very much. By the way, *niice* drawing and answer!

Comment: I used `PowerPoint` with a `LaTeX` add-in called `IguanaTex` for the labels.

Comment: @ja72, why is it that if $\mu$ is greater than co-tangent,   there no limit to the amount of MASS that can be used. surely mass is independent, when the beam is vertical. It is not intuitive for me, can you explain?

Comment: $A_x = \mu A_y$ leads to $$M (\cot\theta - \mu) = m (\mu - \frac{1}{2} \cot\theta)$$ If $\theta \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}$ then a huge amount of friction is needed to keep it stable because or the bottom is going to slide away.

Answer (score 2):

As requested, here's some cut/paste from Amazon's "Look Inside" feature on the Studend Problem Solution manual.   [Solution](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1439048541)

[image: part 1]

[image: part 2]